# JQuery or Javascript to rotate text inside a DIV with text array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have the follow code to rotate text content inside a DIV. It works fine but the messages are displayed random and not in order from first to last, sometimes they even get repeated twice or more

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var textarray = [
        "message one",
        "now message two",
        "last but not least message three"
    ];

    var $ryt=$('#notes');

    function RndText(){
        var rannum=Math.floor(Math.random()*textarray.length);
        $ryt.html(textarray[rannum]).hide().fadeIn('slow');
    }

    onload=function(){
        RndText();
    }

    var inter=setInterval(function(){
        RndText();
    },3000);

</script>
```

The text is displayed and rotation and fade effect works fine inside DIV "notes", the only problem is this math.random that does not display the messages in array from first to last.

I can nothing about javascript. Tested and edited the code the entire day and nothing. Any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to use the jquery function **fadeIn()** to animate a div, See **[WORKED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/L8tjqxLa/1/)** :

- The **[fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)** method gradually changes the opacity, for selected elements, from hidden to visible (fading effect).
- To control animation pass **"slow"** OR **"fast"** OR **indicate durations in milliseconds** in params to the function.

**FULL JS :**

```
setInterval(function(){
    i = i == textArray.length ? 0 : i;   
    $('#notes').text(textArray[i]).hide().fadeIn('slow');
    i++;
},5000);
```

Comment: But it seems to be a good way, can you please check why is not working? I really like your idea

Comment: It's working now just you have to wait the 5 seconds,be patient :).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7fppsemy/)

Following code does the trick you want:

```
function flash() {
   $( "div" ).show().fadeOut( "slow" );
}
```

**__UPDATE__**

Try this then:

**Please pay attention that I changed above div definition slightly.**

```
  function flash() {
      $( "#notes" ).show().fadeOut( "slow" );
  }
```

Comment: does I only need to change the name of the "div" to "notes" only ?

Comment: @nonoyesyes take a look at the fiddle. Play with it to understand how it works.

Comment: I tried but nothing. I am a zero to the left while talking about javscript and jquery